# Text Classification - using stemmer degrades results?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, stemming, text-classification

There's [this](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~mkorayem/paper/survey_Arabic.pdf) article about sentiment analysis of Arabic.

In the beginning of page 5 it says that:

> "Experiments also show that stemming words before feature extraction and classification nearly always degrades the results".

Later on in the same page, they state that:

> "...and an Arabic light stemmer is used for stemming the words"

Um I thought that a stemmer/lemmatizer was *always* used before text classifications, why does he say that it degrades the results?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know the arabic language, it may be specific in many aspects, my answer regards english.

> Um I thought that a stemmer/lemmatizer was always used before text classifications, why does he say that it degrades the results?

No it is not, in entirely depends on the **task**. If you want to extract some general concept of the text, then stemming/lematization is a good step. But in analysis of short chunks, where each word is valuable, stemming simply destroys its meaning. In particular - in sentiment analysis stemming may destroy the sentiment of the word.

Comment: Hi @lejlot :) First thing: thanks. A question: "In analysis of short chunks, stemming simply destroys the meaning"?! O_O Can you please provide an explanation/example/source? And I gave the second quote to show that at the end they _did_ use the stemmer... even though they shouldn't have? (BTW: I don't know Arabic either, but I guess the major difference is in it's being an _very_ inflected language).

Comment: Stemming is just a set of rules of shortening the word, which can lose its meaning in the process. What is so surprising about that? Any manipulation that reduces amount of data - reduces amount of information.Consider a Lancaster stemmer and words: hard
,harder
,hardening
,hards; which have completely different meanings in english, that all have **the same stem** "hard", which makes this process loose lots of information.

Comment: regarding quotation - I did not read the paper, as it is far from being interesting for me; but first, they state that it *nearly always* reduce results, not *always*, maybe in their case it didn't happend, so they can stem, and they state that they use **light** stemmer which might be "light" in the sense of lost meaning. For example Wordnet lemmatizer is much lighter than lancaster stemmer.

Comment: ...And yet it's still being used? I guess it doesn't mean much, but I've read quite a lot and I can't remember seeing any text classification done without stemming. Have you...? Thanks again @lejlot

Comment: Yes, my comment states, that it may be **the case** there, again - **light** may be the crucial point here. And yes, I've seen dozens of such (classification without stemming), especially a modern approaches based on more advanced models than simple bag of words representation, but SO is not the place for such discussions.

Comment: OK... if you have a link of such an article or something like that (of a bag of words model, preferably, without stemming), I'd really appreciate it. Thanks @lejlot :)